# Maximum size of database for DQ mode in Power BI

Tags: performance, powerbi

I am using a database worth of 500 GBs. I want to visualize different columns to study the relationship between them using Power BI. However, there are performance issues while loading graphs.
I am using in DQ mode.
Its annoying to wait for 10 minutes for each visual to load.

Could anyone tell me if its a good idea to use Power BI for visualisation/making dashboard out of 500GBs of data?
What is the maximum limit of database we can use in DQ mode to create visuals efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

DQ doesn't have a defined limit, MS have shown demos using a Petabyte database in this case for long running queries on a database, you have a few options.

1. Understand what queries are being run, and optimise your indexing strategy, maybe for example add a covering index
2. Optimise your data source, by using a column store index to move it in memory
3. Create database or table(s) with a the necessary subset of data from your main data.
4. Examine what objects are being used, and remove nested logic, views on top of views etc, with scalar conditions etc

The petabyte example by MS also used aggregation mode (Mentioned by WB in their answer) to store a subset of the data

I have used Direct Query to sit over data sources that have been around the 200GB range, however these have been mostly standard Star Schema data warehouses, or a defined reporting table, both which had the relevant indexes, covering indexes, or Column Store Indexes to allow more efficient retrieval of data. Direct Query Mode will slow down due to the number of query's that it has the do on the data source based on the measure, relationships and the connection overhead. Another can be the number of visuals on page, as each visual is a query and each one has to run on the data source.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at aggregates in Power BI. You can basically import aggregate tables to Power BI that would satisfy needs for most of your visuals and resort to Direct Query for details that you might rarely need. When properly configured, aggregations will be cached and visuals that hit the aggregation will make use of that while those that don't will seamlessly query the DQ source.

Also, VertiPaq engine with its columnar store is quite efficient at compresses data. So given some smart modelling (get rid of unneeded high cardinality columns), you might actually end up with a much smaller model than your original data for all import.

Your mileage may vary.

As to the dataset limit itself, I believe it's 1GB/dataset when uploading to the service.